# applid background-color whole div tag but only work on a line

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqkr3.png)

I applid  tag background-color but it only works on a line. not entire block

please help me! I almost took 1.5hours for this and I couldn't make it. :(
so sad!

I already tried clear:both and doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj15e.png)

and this is what i exactly want.
how can i ..?
I need you guys' help !

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <style>

    
    div p{
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            height: 10s0px;
            width: 100px;
            font-size: 20spx;
            line-height: 100px;

        }
        h4{
            color:navy;
        }
        .b{
            background-color: gold; 
        }

        .a { 
            background-color: gainsboro;
        }
        .c {
            background-color:rgb(185, 185, 185); 
            clear:both
         }
         
        </style>
    </head>
       <body>
         <div class="c">       
            <h4>HOMEWORK</h4>
        <p class="b">일</p>
        <p class="a">이</p>
        <p class="b">삼</p>
        <p class="a">사</p>
    
    
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using float, which is causing the background problem, use `display:inline-block`. It's saying that each element can have a width and height, but can be next to each other, rather than above.

```css
div {
  color:navy;
}
div p {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.b {
      background-color: gold; 
  }
.a { 
      background-color: gainsboro;
  }
.c {
      background-color:rgb(185, 185, 185);
}
```

```html
<div class="c">       
  <h4>HOMEWORK</h4>
  <p class="b">일</p>
  <p class="a">이</p>
  <p class="b">삼</p>
  <p class="a">사</p>
</div>
```